# get all nodes except nodes with only 2 properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am developing a web application using neo4j and php.

I have 10 properties set for any given node. but some of the nodes have only 2 properties. Now i need all the nodes except the nodes with only those two particular values.

Following is an example query that i want to run
BOY is a label and has name,age,height,weight,runTime ...;
now , some of the nodes only have data in name and age properties

I want to get all the nodes BOY minus BOY with only Name and Age

EX : match (c : BOY) where NOT (c.height ="" AND c.weight ="") return count(c);

But the above query filters some more result that I want to get.

I have tried Multiple variations But still either the syntax is wrong or I am not getting proper results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [missing property evaluates to null](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-where.html#_missing_properties_and_values) so instead of checking for ""

```
 match (c : BOY) where c.height is null and c.weight is null return count(c);
```

(add more properties as necessary to find all nodes that do NOT have all these properties)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I just figured out the solution myself a few min back.